How to use apply legend items to change item order using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
I have a graph that I have at least 3 chart series in it. When I had a 4rth, 5th or 6th series to it; I want two of the chart series to be changed in order.
Here is the documentation for the object:
So I want my legend to look something like this.
series 1
series 4
series 5
series 6
series 2
series 3

(yes it will always be series 2 and 3 I want at the bottom)
For the life of me I am not sure how to apply the legend objects to the actual chart object.
When I instantiate the object, I am unsure of how to apply it to my chart. I don't see where the information gets passed.
Here is an example for simply switching the order.
How do I actually pick the order though?
Also, how would I pick where to place the legend onto the chart?
public Legend alterchartlegend(Chart viscositychart)
{
    Legend  chartlegend = new Legend();

    chartlegend.LegendItemOrder = LegendItemOrder.ReversedSeriesOrder;

    return chartlegend;
}


Not an expert but I see 2 options. (1): maintain a separate list of series, from that list you define the series of the chart, passing it [1,2,3] or [1,4,2,3] or [1,4,5,2,3] etc etc. Or (2): try using the Chart.CustomizeLegend event as shown in this answer.

That's a pretty clever idea! I like that one actually. I'd have to rework alot of my code though.
